# Write string to virtual file?

Tags: php, fopen, shell-exec, virtual-file

Our teacher has a web server and we are allowed to test some things. I connected to the server with Putty and tried following command:

```
echo "i 4 r 255 g 0 b 0." > /dev/ttyACM0
```

`ttyACM0` is a virtual file redirecting the stream to a serial interface. This specific command changes the color of a rgb led. But the same command doesn't work in php with `exec` or `shell_exec`:

```
<?php
    // Script saved at /home/STUDENT_NAME/public_html/blink.php
    echo shell_exec("echo \"i 4 r 255 g 0 b 0.\" > /dev/ttyACM0"); // Doesn't work
    echo shell_exec("echo \"Hello\""); // Returns "Hello"
?>
```

I know that `exec` and `shell_exec` aren't disabled, because the second call to `shell_exec` works. My next idea was to use `fopen("php://memory", "a");`, but I don't know how to use these wrappers. So my questions:

- How to use these wrappers correctly? (Maybe like `"php://memory/dev/ttyACM0"`)
- Is there a better solution?

Comment: `public_html` suggests Apache. Is the web server user allowed to write into that file? Also, lack of error messages suggests you haven't configured PHP to display them.

Answer (score 1):

When you work on the file through the web, all file accesses are performed through the user the web server is running as, which is likely different from the user you login as through PuTTY. Thus you might be encountering a permission issue. Check the permissions on the tty device:

> ls -l /dev/ttyACM0

I guess it will be group-writable, so take note of the group and check if your user is part of that group:

> groups

Then check if the user the HTTP server is running as has the same right:

> ps aux | grep http

This should show a list of all processes containing *http* in their name, and the web server will likely be among them. Identify it, and the first column of the corresponding line will tell you the user the web server is using. Let's suppose it is *apache*. Now run:

> groups apache

(Or whatever you discovered in the previous step) This will show you the groups the user belongs to, and I bet the group ttyACM0 belongs to will not be among those. You will need to ask the sysadmin to add the user to the group.

Anyway using `shell_exec` in that context is very bad practice. I think you can just open the serial device and write to it:

```
$fp = fopen ("/dev/ttyACM0", "w");
fwrite ($fp, "i 4 r 255 g 0 b 0.\n");
fclose ($fp);
```

Of course this won't work if the HTTP server user does not have the permission to write to the device. Also, make sure to pay attention to the line termination in the `fwrite()`, you might need it or not, or even need a different one (`\r` or `\r\n`);

Comment: The device allows all members of `dialout` to read and write (crw-rw----). My user is member of this group. The output of the 3rd command means nothing to me (`STUDENT_NAME 12425 0.0 0.0 13252 924 pts/0 S+ 17:37 0:00 grep --color=auto http` with http in red) and `error_get_last()` says `failed to open stream: Permission denied` even though I am member of `dialout` and it worked for my user in Putty.

Comment: I figured out that I can manipulate the file via command line with either `echo` and `php script_name`, but not within my browser.

Comment: What you're missing if that when you work on the file through the web, all file accesses are not made by your user, but through the user the web server is running as! The ps command above should display another line besides the one you reported, whose first column will tell you the user the web server is using. If then you run the 'groups' command on that user, it will show you the groups the user belongs to, and I bet _dialout_ will not be among those. The "Permission denied" error clearly says so.

Comment: I've just incorporated part of the previous comment in my answer. It should be clearer now.